# Catching exception in asyncio stream server

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, python-asyncio

Given the following program:

```
1    import asyncio
2    async def run():
3        try:
4            server = await asyncio.start_server(on_connected, '127.0.0.1', 15500)
5
6            async with server:
7                await server.serve_forever()
8        except:
9            print("exception!")
10 
11   async def on_connected(reader, writer):
12       while True:
13           data = await reader.readline()
14           print(1 / 0)
15   
16   asyncio.run(run())
```

When I run it, and use `nc` to connect to it & send data, it will raise an exception in line `14`. However I am *unable* to handle it. Instead, I will get an exception printed and the program will *hang*.

`nc` test:

```
$ nc localhost 15500
test
```

program output:

```
$ python3 serv
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<on_connected() done, defined at serv:14> exception=ZeroDivisionError('division by zero')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "serv", line 14, in on_connected
    print(1 / 0)
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

While *I of course could* just add a `try/except` around line `14`, I want to implement **a general exception handling** which shall handle all errors which can ever occur inside of `on_connected`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asyncio provides a method to [set a general exception handler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.set_exception_handler)

Let's apply it to this example:

- Let's just define our loop exception handler: handle_exception
- And inside this method let's manage exceptions. Next code just customize logging messages.

```
import asyncio
import logging

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


async def run():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    loop.set_exception_handler(handle_exception)
    server = await asyncio.start_server(on_connected, '127.0.0.1', 5062)

    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()

async def on_connected(reader, writer):
    while True:
        data = await reader.readline()
        raise print(1 / 0)

def handle_exception(loop, context):
    # context["message"] will always be there; but context["exception"] may not
    msg = context.get("exception", context["message"])
    if name := context.get("future").get_coro().__name__ == "on_connected":
        if type(msg) == ZeroDivisionError:
            log.error(f"Caught ZeroDivisionError from on_connected: {msg}")
            return
        log.info(f"Caught another minor exception from on_connected: {msg}")
    else:
        log.error(f"Caught exception from {name}: {msg}")
```

Output on this case is the following:

```
Caught ZeroDivisionError from on_connected: division by zero
```

Reference that I have used to look for further information:

- https://www.roguelynn.com/words/asyncio-exception-handling/
  https://github.com/econchick/mayhem/blob/master/part-3/mayhem_2.py

Please, let me know if this answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

When developing server code, bug causing an exception often occurs and then the server process just hangs and must be killed, which is super anoying.

I wanted it to exit cleanly as soon as one exception is raised in the protocol code. To do so, I created a handler class that closes the server and registered it as the exception handler. The call to `await server.serve_forever()` will throw `CancelledError`, so you may want to catch it to exit cleanly.

```py
import asyncio


class ExcHandler:
    def __init__(self, server):
        self._server = server

    def __call__(self, loop, context):
        print("exception occured, closing server")
        loop.default_exception_handler(context)
        self._server.close()

class EchoServerProtocol(asyncio.Protocol):
    def connection_made(self, transport):
        raise RuntimeError("oups")


async def main():
    
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()

    server = await loop.create_server(
        lambda: EchoServerProtocol(),
        '127.0.0.1', 8888)

    loop.set_exception_handler(ExcHandler(server))

    async with server:
        try:
            await server.serve_forever()
        except asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError:
            print("server cancelled")

asyncio.run(main())
```

Apparently, the server catching exceptions is by design (See [Python issue #42526](https://bugs.python.org/issue42526)). The rationale behind that is the server keeps processing other requests, even when one of them crash. I guess this is suitable for production where the show must go on even in case of glitches.